# PageView Controller errors 'Expected selector for Objective C'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I'm having so much trouble creating a pageview controller. I have made adjustments to my code three times but i KEEP getting the following error: ' Expected selector for Objective C method'. I also get another error message which says Missing '@end'. Could anyone please tell me why I recieve these messages? :l

```
    #import "InstructionContentViewController.h"
    #import "StorageViewController.h"

    @interface StorageViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation StorageViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad

    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create the data model
    _pageTitles = @[@"Over 200 Tips and Tricks", @"Discover Hidden Features", @"Bookmark     Favorite Tip", @"Free Regular Update"];
    _pageImages = @[@"instructions1.png", @"instructions2.png", @"instructions3.png", @"instructions4.png"];

    // Create page view controller
    self.instructionViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InstructionViewController"];
    self.instructionViewController.dataSource = self;

    InstructionContentViewController *startInstructViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startInstructViewController];
    [self.instructionViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.instructionViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 50);

    [self addChildViewController:_instructionViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_instructionViewController.view];
    [self.instructionViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

     }

     - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
     {
      [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
      }

     - (IBAction)startWalkthrough:(id)sender {

    InstructionContentViewController *startingInstructViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingInstructViewController];
    [self.instructionViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source Methods:

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((InstructionContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

      index--;
      return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
    }

      - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController      viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    {
    NSUInteger index = ((InstructionContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
    }

     - (InstructionContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
    {
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    InstructionContentViewController *instructionContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InstructionContentViewController"];
    instructionContentViewController.instructimageFile = self.pageImages[index];
    instructionContentViewController.instructtitleText = self.pageTitles[index];
    instructionContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

    return instructionContentViewController;


    }


       - (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController     *)pageViewController
     {
    return [self.pageTitles count];
    }

    - (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}



     @end
```

Comment: Most likely you got some bad invisible characters in your code. Can you copy paste it to a texteditor and back in for example?

Comment: tried that twice and had no luck :l

Comment: I just pasted your code into Xcode and, after removing all unknown symbols, it compiles just fine (the compiler doesn't care about terrible code style, but you should definitely try to adapt the official Objective-C coding guidelines). It seems @NickWeaver is correct and there are some strange invisible symbols in your code.  In which lines do you get the errors?

Comment: Hi David thanks for the reply. I get error in the  @interface 'StorageViewController (),  end, implementation' StorageViewController' part of the code. Really cannot figure this out and it's driving me crazy! It's been almost a whole day of trying to fix this.

Comment: Have you thought about removing the class extension at the top? That seems to be the code causing you issues and it doesn't look like you're using it for anything.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that a syntax error exists in one of the files you `#import`, either InstructionContentViewController.h or StorageViewController.h.

Due to how imports are handled, the warning can sometimes show up in unexpected place. Verify that those are well-formed, as well as any other files that may be imported from those.

Also, within Xcode you can click on the "Product" menu and hold the Option key for a 'Clean Build Folder' command. This will clear out pre-compiled data and force everything to be recompiled from scratch.